# How to add an additional value to an existing key in Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, addition, bioinformatics, key-value-store

I'm new to programming and I am trying to work my way into Python for biological purposes. Currently I want to test myself in calculating the GC content of DNA sequences in FASTA format. My apologies if this question has already been answered in some way but I couldn't transfer any of the possible solutions to my specific problem (probably/hopefully due to lacking experience).

So, for the above mentioned purpose I created a dictionary with the single-lines (containing the identifier in the FASTA file) as keys and the corresponding DNA sequences as str values. My idea was to add the calculated GC content (a float) as an additional value to the existing keys so that you have everything together. But I'm still failing in this last step.

So how do you add additional values to an existing key? I've tried to use

```
dictionary[key].append(GC_content)
```

as I do with lists to add the GC content. But I get an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.

This is what I do for calculating the GC content and to add the second value in the dictionary:

```
GC_counter = 0
for key in dictionary:
    for char in dictionary[key]:
        if char == 'G' or char == 'C':
            GC_counter += 1
    GC_content = GC_counter/float(len(dictionary[key]))*100
    dictionary[key].append(GC_content)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you modify the signature of your dict? A default dict would do nicely here.

Comment: What are your `dict's` content. Please post a sample to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of approaching this. To answer your original question, if you are determined to put the GC content in the key of a pre-existing dictionary then this will work:

```
d = {'read1': 'ATGCATGCTAGCATGAC',
     'read2': 'ATGCATTTGACCAGTGA'}
for key, seq in d.copy().iteritems():
    gc_counter = 0
    for base in seq:
        if base in ['G', 'C']:
            gc_counter += 1.
    gc_content = gc_counter / len(seq) * 100.
    d['{}_{}'.format(key, gc_content)] = d.pop(key)
```

Which returns:

```
{'read1_47.0588235294': 'ATGCATGCTAGCATGAC', 'read2_41.1764705882': 'ATGCATTTGACCAGTGA'}
```

However, I would suggest just adding it in as an additional value to the dictionary to make things a little neater and make it easier to access the GC content later:

```
d = {
    'read1': 'ATGCATGCTAGCATGAC',
    'read2': 'ATGCATTTGACCAGTGA'
}
for key, seq in d.iteritems():
    gc_counter = 0
    for base in seq:
        if base in ['G', 'C']:
            gc_counter += 1.
    gc_content = gc_counter / len(seq) * 100.
    d[key] = {'seq': seq, 'gc_content': gc_content}
```

Then you would access a read's GC content as `d[read]['gc_content']`.

You mentioned you are doing this for the purposes of getting used to Python so I won't go into detail about how there is libraries for doing this automatically (I assume you probably know this anyways) but will point you in the direction of [Biopython](http://biopython.org/). Taken from their docs you could do something like this:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC
my_seq = Seq('GATCGATGGGCCTATATAGGATCGAAAATCGC', IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
GC(my_seq) # 46.875
```

Comment: Also, for future reference, there is now a [bioinformatics stack exchange community](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions related more so to bioinformatics.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I'm really sorry for replying that late but it helped me out a lot. And you are definitely right, Biopython is the way to go,but somehow I wanted to try it by myself in order to get used to Python.